# What is a word that means "the state of having an organic nature"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the following paragraph:

> Gramsci believed that languages created in a laboratory (i.e. Esperanto) do not develop organically in the mind of a nation and its individuals.  The imposition of externally derived rules and language that have no 'organic nature' (*Italian: organicità*) was tantamount to putting the mind in a straitjacket.

What word could be substituted for 'organic nature'?

*organicity* & *organicness* seem like possibilities, but I've never come across either of them.

Comment: BTW, it's a common error to use "i.e." for "e.g.". Esperanto is not the only such language alluded to. There are also Loglan, Klingon, and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to say something about the meaning, since I speak Italian natively.

**Organicità** in Italian is an "*ordered, harmonious and rational connection among the various parts of a whole*". (It makes sense in English, right?)

So, **Organico** means "to be well-balanced, harmonious and ordered in all its parts".

The phrase Sam suggested is ok, although it describes the situation from a slightly different point of view. I looked up **Organicity** and I only found it on the OED. So it exists in English, or better, it "existed" because, looking at the [Ngram Viwer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=organicity&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3), I suppose it's not really that used lately.

Comment: “Organic nature” is [more used](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=organicity%2Corganic+nature&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than “organicity”.

Comment: @F'x: So there are no corresponding single words in English?

Comment: There are, but not with this root: **coherence**, **integration**, **harmony**, **coordination**, …

Comment: I see. I wonder why English didn't keep Organicty, but I guess it's OT for this question. Thanks for the list anyway!

Comment: @Alenanno: I realised that my list is a possible answer to the question, so I reposted it as such :)

Comment: Ahahah you see? I helped you.

Comment: @Alenanno I saw too that 'organicity' is a word, and it seems to be used mostly in a psychological context.  Perhaps its use was attached to a fad in psychology that peaked in the 80s. Interesting though, I find that the English usage of 'organic' has little to do with harmony, etc. among the parts of the whole.  I could be wrong.  It seems like a very interesting nuance between languages.

Comment: @gbutters: Yes I saw that as well. I am unaware why, honestly. The first literal meaning in italian for "organico" is "provided with organs, derived from living organisms". Even if "living organism" is a repetition, because an organism is always living (an individual animal, plant, or single-celled life form).

Answer (score 3):

According to Wiktionary, [organicità](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/organicit%C3%A0) translates to "organic unity." Assuming we're in the ballpark with that and "organic nature," the sentence leads me to think "organic integrity" is close to the mark.

If the single word is what you're after, consider "acculturation."

Answer (score 3):

I would rephrase the whole sentence to something like:

> The imposition of externally derived
>   rules and language that didn't evolve organically
>   was tantamount to putting the mind in
>   a straitjacket.

Answer (score 3):

Organic here has the meaning of 'denoting or characterized by a harmonious relationship between the elements of a whole' (see [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0585560#m_en_gb0585560)). They give the example: 'the organic unity of the integral work of art'.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest: **coherence**, **integration**, **harmony**, or **coordination**.

Comment: Based on Alenanno's description of the meaning, I'd say "coherence" is the best fit.